# How to create custom Flex 4 components

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, components, builder

I've created a extended Scroller component based on Spark Scroller... (only AS3 Code/no MXML)

the neu component is list on the component library on the left window of flash builder in the custom section...

1. how can i change the section to a own section
2. how can i replace the icon of the component
3. when I drag the component into the stage, it has a size of (100,0) Pixel... if I drag the original Scroller to the stage... there pops up a dialog for customize the scroller-size....
   how can I predefine the size? or create a dialog by dropping my component?

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/create-professional-flex-components/

Comment: 1 and 2 finished ... thanks for that... any ideas for the 3. question?

Comment: Somewhere I've seen blog posts about how to conditionally change your logic in design view, but in the minute or two I have right now, I haven't been able to find it.  Try searching on "Flex conditional design view" or similar terms.